# the return value of "org.json.simple.JSONObject.get(Object)" is null even though HTTP request is successful?

Tags: java, json, netbeans

So I'm using the Rapid API alpha vantage API to retrieve some stock data. Wrote this code 2 months ago and it successfully printed out the stock price, but when I ran it again today it through this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Double.doubleValue()" because the return value of "org.json.simple.JSONObject.get(Object)" is null
```

I tried the testing the endpoint on RapidAPI's API playground, which worked. Then I tried calling the json without requesting a specific address and the json was retrieved successfully
([Pic of what the json response looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpU8t.png)) It just seems that issues crop up when I call this:

```
double price = (Double) jsonObject.get("05. price");
```

Here is my code. I censored my API key and stuff:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Helper.requestPrice();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static void requestPrice() throws Exception{
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String ticker = "msft";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol="+ticker+"&datatype=json")
    .get()
    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com")
    .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxxxx")
    .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        
        String myData = response.body().string();//works
        
        Object obj = JSONValue.parse(myData);  //works
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;  //works
        double price = (Double) jsonObject.get("05. price");  
        System.out.println(price);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: @AxelRichter So I just tried both of your tips and it seems that everything, including JSONValue.parse(myData), works as the JSON is successfully outputted. I think i attached an image of the successful json request output in the post above as well. So somehow something goes wrong when I request a specific address "05. price", any tips regarding this?